# unable to display tables and diagrams in python for non deterministic finite automata

Tags: python, automata, finite-automata, nfa, automata-theory

I want to ask for help to solve this problem, I wonder if there is something wrong with my code or are there tools or extensions that I haven't installed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiolJ.jpg)

I've tried to follow the suggestions on other websites and also YouTube, but still can't solve this problem, please help me friends

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code